# Keyboard Toolbar buttons not showing

Tags: ios, swiftui, keyboard

I am using the [example from HWS](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-a-toolbar-to-the-keyboard) but I'm having no luck getting buttons to show above the keyboard.

Xcode 13.2.1 / Physical device running iOS 15.3.1

Is this a known issue?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardView: View {
    @State private var name = "Neil"

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Click me!") {
                        print("Clicked")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi I test with my device, I have no problem. Iphone 13 Pro -> IOS 15.3.1 -> XCODE 13.2.1

Comment: works fine with me as well - also in Simulator iPhone 12, iOS 15.2, Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: Are you simply displaying KeyboardView or is KeyboardView a child view of some other view? I am having issues with this as well in my app. One "work around" has been wrapping the TextField in a NavigationView, but that will probably break your layout as it does mine since NavigationView's take up as much available space as possible.

Comment: I am using the exact code as above. I’ll try the navigation view and test if I can at least see some buttons - thanks

Comment: So wrapping around a NavigationView allowed me to at least see the button. Feels like a bug. Thanks.

Comment: Not a bug. `.toolBar` has to have a `NavigationView` to operate. Same for `.navigationTitle`, `NavigationLink()`, etc.

Comment: Interesting how the HWS doesn't show this.

Comment: Logically, it makes no sense that a `NavigationView` is required for a keyboard toolbar to work. We aren't navigating anywhere. I think it's a bug. And I know that I had this working without a `NavigationView` a few months ago, but now I can confirm it's not working for me without a `NavigationView`. (Xcode 13.3.1, iOS 15.4.1)

Comment: It does not work if you should a UIViewRepresentable UITextView.

Comment: @jat have you found any solution for 15.3.1 or you are facing same issues with other OSes as well ?

Comment: @Mrunal still using NavigationView

Comment: I have the same issue with iOS 16, the button appears only when I shake the phone and the system shows the Alert to undo the text.

Comment: Please everyone file a bug report

Answer (score 6):

1. Put your parent view inside a NavigationStack or NavigationView
2. Put your text view in a NavigationView (not stack)

```swift
struct KeyboardView: View {
    @State private var name = "Neil"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                    Button("Click me!") {
                        print("Clicked")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                KeyboardView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on: Xcode 15 beta 5

Comment: This worked for me on iOS 17. Strange!

Comment: Is that a hack as I never see adding any element to `NavigationView` also the navigation view is deprecated so how long this solution going to work :|